# Unable to load oracledb

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I'm upgrading my Node js application from version 8 to version 10
suddenly when i tried to run the application it throws an error with the description bellow

> cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 10.9.0 (win32, x64)
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the
>   module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
>   Node-oracledb installation instructions:
>   https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

if i downgrade my nodejs to version 8, it works like a charm, my application uses some version 10 features that recently added
i have tried to remove all modules and then i typed `npm install` in order to reinstall modules properly i got failed with message above.
i also tried to follow [node js installation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin) with no luck, what should i do ?

Comment: `npm upgrade oracledb` will solve the issue

Comment: Did you try the `npm upgrade`? Another option is to uninstall oracledb and then reinstall it. Ultimately, oracledb uses a binary that's specific to a given version/ABI of Node.js.

Comment: Check the first comment

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize that was you. You should post your answer as an answer and then accept it (may take 2 days).

Comment: @DanMcGhan it will not have enough information so it will be marked as low quality answer